# Merge items in an array including sub items

Tags: node.js, arrays, sorting

I have an array that is as follows:

```
 [
  {
    Region: 'Sionnach',
    Area: 'Station',
    Codes: '76534675'
  },
  {
    Region: 'Cape',
    Area: 'Dreg',
    Codes: '73457347'
  },
  {
    Region: 'Cape',
    Area: 'Dreg',
    Codes: '7653737'
  },
  {
    Region: 'Stone',
    Area: 'Lights',
    Codes: '612342136'
  },
  { 
    Region: 'Stone',
    Area: 'Pram',
    Codes:'73247237'
  },
]
```

I want it to appear as the following:

```
  [
    {
      Region: "Sionnach",
      Area: {
        Station: {
          Codes: "76534675",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      Region: "Cape",
      Area: {
        Dreg: {
          Codes: "73457347",
          Codes: "7653737",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      Region: "Stone",
      Area: {
        Lights: {
          Codes: "612342136",
        },
        Pram: {
          Codes: "73247237",
        },
      },
    },
  ]
```

Can someone please let me know how I can accomplish this?
I've tried numerous ways but I can't seem to figure out what I need to do, its probably really simple, been sitting here for 3 hours and I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have an object with two identical keys like

```
{ Codes: "73457347", Codes: "7653737" }
```

So I would suggest saving them as an array simply because a region area seems to might have more than one code.

To achieve what you want:

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the region is the `key` and the expected grouped region object is the `value`. In each iteration, get the current region record if it exists. Then, update its `Area` object where the current area is the key and its codes list is the value. Finally, update the Map using [`Map#set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set).
- Using [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), you get in the end the grouped list of regions with their corresponding areas.

```js
const arr =  [ { Region: 'Sionnach', Area: 'Station', Codes: '76534675' }, { Region: 'Cape', Area: 'Dreg', Codes: '73457347' }, { Region: 'Cape', Area: 'Dreg', Codes: '7653737' }, { Region: 'Stone', Area: 'Lights', Codes: '612342136' }, { Region: 'Stone', Area: 'Pram', Codes:'73247237' } ];

const res = [...
  arr.reduce((map, { Region, Area, Codes }) => {
    const regionAreas = map.get(Region)?.Area ?? {};
    regionAreas[Area] = [...(regionAreas[Area] ?? []), Codes];
    map.set(Region, { Region, Area: regionAreas });
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```